# jQuery leaving hover does not show correct content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a select time via an analog clock. My current problem is that when I make a hover to the hour-div. It should show something else (now text "Hovering") when hovering, and go back to the hour-text when leaving (for example "10"). Problem is that when leaving, all hour-divs get set to the text "12" (the last div made by the script).

I do not see why it does not work as intended. Maybe you do?

Here is the script:

```
'use strict'

var d  = 12; // number of hours
var cx = 200;
var cy = 200;
var r  = 40;
var a  = 2*Math.PI/d; // angle of one hour in radians
var s  = a*2; // Displace starting of the circle to fit a clock
for(var i=0; i<d; i++) {
  var x  = Math.round(cx + r*Math.cos(a*i-s));
  var y  = Math.round(cy + r*Math.sin(a*i-s));
  var ii = i+1;
  var space = (ii<10 ? "&nbsp;":"");
  $('.circle').append('<div class="slices" id="slice'+ii+'">'+space+ii+'</div>');
  $('#slice'+ii).css({left:x,top:y}).hover(
    function () {
      $(this).html("Hovering");
    },
    function () {
      $(this).html(space+ii);
    }
  );
}
```

To see it in action, see http://plnkr.co/edit/ORuRyr?p=preview

Comment: That is because in the loop your are updating your `ii` and after the loop it is 12. So when you are replacing your HTML after hover, your `ii` is 12 and get put into your div's. You need to 'remember' what the HTML was when hovering the div and put that back when hovering out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @putvande said in the comments is right, but you don't necessarily need to "remember" anything — you can just extract the correct number from the element's `id`.

To do this, replace the line

```
$(this).html(space+ii);
```

with

```
$(this).html(this.id.substring(5));
```

Comment: @EricC Great, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Declare a var to keep track of hovered li and on callback replace it.

```
    var text = '';
      $('#slice'+ii).css({left:x,top:y}).hover(    
        function () {
          text = $(this).html();
          $(this).html("Hovering");
        },
        function () {
          $(this).html(space+text);
        }
      );
```

Update to demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUXuTK?p=preview)

Comment: Actually even a little bit better than the accepted solution, since it keeps my &nbsp; for numbers less than 10 (note that the "space" is not needed, as it has the same problem has with the initial "ii"-usage, but it is no longer needed since the original div-text is saved in the variable text). Thanks!

Comment: @EricC just a note about accepted answer. `this.id.substring(5)` will  also act same and it's faster than `.attr()` or `.prop()`.